# gen_event handler crashes in init. Where?

Tags: erlang

I've got a `gen_event` handler that crashes in `Handler:init`. The only visible result of this is that the handler is not added, and the result of `gen_event:which_handlers` does not contain my handler.

How do I detect that this is happening and write something appropriate (preferably including a stack trace) to the console or log?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If it fails when you add it, you can write `ok = gen_event:add_handler(EventMgrRef, Handler, Args)` so it will not fail silently.

If it fails later, during execution, you can choose `ok = gen_event:add_sup_handler(EventMgrRef, Handler, Args)` to add a supervised handler.

Comment: Ah, the piece I was missing is that `init` completes before `add_handler` (or `add_sup_handler`) returns, which means that you'll see something other than `ok`, if `init` crashes.

Comment: ...I was expecting something in SASL (or lager) about dying processes.

Comment: @RogerLipscombe - That's the thing about gen_event: the handlers are not individual processes. The gen_event process lives on even if its handler(s) fail.